# Change markup elements based on value of MVC Listbox and Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Suppose I have the following markup in my MVC view:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <label>UI Element:</label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedUIItem, Model.UIItems)
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UseWholeMarkup)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m =>m.UseWholeMarkup)
            </div>

            </div>
```

I want to take the value of the Drop Down and the Checkbox and dynamically change what I will display below these elements without a postback. Do I need to use JQuery/JavaScript to do this? How?

The View Model is:

```
 // DropDownList
        public string SelectedUIItem { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UIItems { get; set; }

        // Checkbox
        [DisplayName("Use Whole Markup ")]
        public bool UseWholeMarkup { get; set; }
```

And the drop down is populated with:

```
List<SelectListItem> listUIItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
            // DropDownList
            SelectListItem selList2 = new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "HEADER",
                Value = "HEADER",
                Selected = false
            };
            listUIItems.Add(selList2);
            selList2 = new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "BODY",
                Value = "BODY",
                Selected = false
            };
            listUIItems.Add(selList2);
            // DropDownList
            selList2 = new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "FOOTER",
                Value = "FOOTER",
                Selected = false
            };
            listUIItems.Add(selList2);
            UIItemsViewModel viewModel = new UIItemsViewModel
            {
                UIItems = listUIItems
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

By "without a postback", I take you to mean without reloading the page. Using AJAX very well may require a POST, but it would not cause the page to reload. Anyways, yes, if you want to change a portion of the page without reloading the whole page, you must use JavaScript. If you want to change that portion via something retrieved from the server, then specifically, you must use AJAX.

Comment: Providing a complete sample that would make any sense is beyond the scope of StackOverflow. You are responsible for taking a stab at a solution, then we can help you with specific problems you may run into.